# SQLite3/C++ Only outputting one row of data

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm having an issue where only one of my 2 test rows will output in C++. My code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*Definitions*/
sqlite3 *db;
void *arg;
char *err;
const char* stmt = "SELECT * from table";
/*End of Definitions*/

int exec(void *arg, int argc, char **argv, char **column) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << column[i] << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "------" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &db); /*Open db "test.sqlite"*/
    if(!rc) {
        while(true) {
            sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, exec, arg, &err);
            if(err) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /*Ending Stuff (NOTHING BEYOND THIS POINT)*/
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting any errors; it is purely just outputting the first row. `cout << err << endl;` will not output anything. Any help is appreciated, thanks. Also, I made a post about this 2 days ago but due to me not receiving help, I am reposting. @CL. happened to make a comment on my previous post saying my SQL was incorrect but I am still yet to figure out what he meant by that

Comment: @CL. I even admitted it was a duplicate, due to the fact you barely gave me any way to resolve my issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

sqlite3_exec () is used to execute insert update statements. For select use sqlite3_prepare (...)

Comment: Thanks, I will get this setup and hopefully have this working.